# Big CSV exportation blocks user session with PHP

Tags: php, csv, export

I'm trying to export a lot of data trough a CSV export. The amount of data it's really big, around 100.000 records and counting.

My client usually uses two tabs to browse and check several stuff at the same time. So a requirement is that while the export is being made, he can continues browsing the system.

The issue is that when the CSV is being generated on the server, the session is blocked, you cannot load another page until the generation is completed.

This is what I'm doing:

1. Open the file
2. Loop trough the amount of data(One query per cycle, each cycle queries 5000 records) pd: I cannot change this, because of certain limitations.
3. write the data into the file
4. free memory
5. close the file
6. set headers to begin download

During the entire process, it's not possible to navigate the site in another tab.

The block of code:

```
$temp       = 1;
$first      = true;
$fileName   = 'csv_data_' . date("Y-m-d") . '-' . time() . '.csv';
$filePath   = CSV_EXPORT_PATH . $fileName;

// create CSV file
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'a');

// get data
for ($i = 1; $i <= $temp; $i++) {

    // get lines
    $data  = $oPB->getData(ROWS_PER_CYCLE, $i); // ROWS_PER_CYCLE = 5000

    // if something is empty, exit
    if (empty($data)) {
        break;
    }

    // write the data that will be exported into a file
    fwrite($fp, $export->arrayToCsv($data, '', '', $first));

    // count element
    $temp   = ceil($data[0]->foundRows / ROWS_PER_CYCLE); // foundRows is always the same value, doesn't change per query.
    $first  = false; // hide header for next rows

    // free memory
    unset($lines);
}

// close file
fclose($fp);

/**
 * Begin Download
 */
$export->csvDownload($filePath); // set headers
```

**Some considerations:**

1. The count is being made in the same query, but it's not entering into an infinite loop, works as expected. It's contained into $data[0]->foundRows, and avoids an unnecesary query to count all the available records.
2. There're several memory limitations due to environment settings, that I cannot change.

Does anyone know How can I improve this? Or any other solution.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm replying only because it can be helpful to someone else. A colleague came up with a solution for this problem.

Call the function **[session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-write-close.php)** before

```
$temp       = 1;
```

Doing this, you're ending the current session and storing the session data, so I'm being able to download the file a continue navigating in other tabs.

I hope it helps some one.

Some considerations about this solution:

1. You must no require to use session data after session_write_close()
2. The export script is in another file. For ex: home.php calls trough a link export.php